# Version sort on FreeBSD?

Tags: regex, sorting, freebsd

I have to sort many thousand files in the correct order on a FreeBSD 10 system. The output will be piped into another program.

This is the result I want:

```
video_title.mp4Frag1Num0.ts
video_title.mp4Frag2Num1.ts
video_title.mp4Frag3Num2.ts
video_title.mp4Frag4Num3.ts
video_title.mp4Frag5Num4.ts
video_title.mp4Frag6Num5.ts
video_title.mp4Frag7Num6.ts
video_title.mp4Frag8Num7.ts
video_title.mp4Frag9Num8.ts
video_title.mp4Frag10Num9.ts
video_title.mp4Frag11Num10.ts
video_title.mp4Frag12Num11.ts
video_title.mp4Frag13Num12.ts
video_title.mp4Frag14Num13.ts
video_title.mp4Frag15Num14.ts
video_title.mp4Frag16Num15.ts
video_title.mp4Frag17Num16.ts
video_title.mp4Frag18Num17.ts
video_title.mp4Frag19Num18.ts
video_title.mp4Frag20Num19.ts
video_title.mp4Frag21Num20.ts
...
```

If I run `ls -1 | sort --version-sort` in the file directory on the FreeBSD system, this is the result:

```
video_title.mp4Frag100Num99.ts
video_title.mp4Frag101Num100.ts
video_title.mp4Frag102Num101.ts
video_title.mp4Frag103Num102.ts
video_title.mp4Frag104Num103.ts
video_title.mp4Frag105Num104.ts
video_title.mp4Frag106Num105.ts
video_title.mp4Frag107Num106.ts
video_title.mp4Frag108Num107.ts
video_title.mp4Frag109Num108.ts
video_title.mp4Frag10Num9.ts
video_title.mp4Frag110Num109.ts
video_title.mp4Frag111Num110.ts
video_title.mp4Frag112Num111.ts
video_title.mp4Frag113Num112.ts
video_title.mp4Frag114Num113.ts
video_title.mp4Frag115Num114.ts
video_title.mp4Frag116Num115.ts
video_title.mp4Frag117Num116.ts
video_title.mp4Frag118Num117.ts
...
```

If I copy a file directory to a Debian Wheezy system and run `ls -1 | sort --version-sort`, the result is correct:

```
video_title.mp4Frag1Num0.ts
video_title.mp4Frag2Num1.ts
video_title.mp4Frag3Num2.ts
video_title.mp4Frag4Num3.ts
video_title.mp4Frag5Num4.ts
video_title.mp4Frag6Num5.ts
video_title.mp4Frag7Num6.ts
video_title.mp4Frag8Num7.ts
video_title.mp4Frag9Num8.ts
video_title.mp4Frag10Num9.ts
video_title.mp4Frag11Num10.ts
video_title.mp4Frag12Num11.ts
video_title.mp4Frag13Num12.ts
video_title.mp4Frag14Num13.ts
video_title.mp4Frag15Num14.ts
video_title.mp4Frag16Num15.ts
video_title.mp4Frag17Num16.ts
video_title.mp4Frag18Num17.ts
video_title.mp4Frag19Num18.ts
video_title.mp4Frag20Num19.ts
...
```

What can I do to sort the files correctly on the FreeBSD system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU coreutils sort and FreeBSD sort have different notions of what a version sort is.

GNU's info documentation says:

```
--version-sort  
    Sort by version name and number.  It behaves like a standard sort,
    except that each sequence of decimal digits is treated numerically
    as an index/version number.
```

The man page for [FreeBSD sort](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sort&sektion=1&n=1) says:

```
-V, --version-sort
    Sort version numbers.  The input lines are treated as file names
    in form PREFIX VERSION SUFFIX, where SUFFIX matches the regular
    expression "(.([A-Za-z~][A-Za-z0-9~]*)?)*".
```

Remember that regex; I'll get back to it in a minute.

What the BSD man page doesn't say, and I've verified this by reading the source code, is that it will sort using the prefix+version as the primary key and the suffix as the secondary key. This means that

```
prog-10.c
prog-11.c
prog-9.cc
prog-9.c
```

will version-sort as

```
prog-9.c
prog-9.cc
prog-10.c
prog-11.c
```

What does this mean to you? With a filename like `video_title.mp4Frag115Num114.ts`, it thinks the suffix is `.mp4Frag115Num114.ts`. It will sort first by the part before prefix (in your case, that'll always be `video_title`), then lexicographically by the suffix. Nuts.

Workarounds:

- install `coreutils` from  ports, which will install GNU sort as `/usr/local/bin/gsort`.
- use @triplee's answer to specify exactly which fields you want numerically sorted.

  `sort -t g -n -k2`

  sets `g` to be the field separator and sorts numerically on the 2nd field.
- change the input to `sort` so that the part you care about doesn't get treated as a suffix, for example

  `sed 's/Frag/Frag-/'|sort --version-sort|sed 's/Frag-/Frag/'`

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a one-off with exactly these files,

```
sort -t g -k2n
```